# I am using Dictionary with list and tuple,how can read items of list

Tags: c#

I am using Dictionary with tuple as a parameter.

```
Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, int>>> dict = 
    new Dictionary<int,List<Tuple<string,int>>>();
```

how can read list items .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int>>> dict = 
new Dictionary<string,List<Tuple<string,int>>>();

Comment: @EdPlunkett so he did, I missed that until your edit.  I appreciate you clarifying :)

Comment: @imannasser My apologies for not realizing you had all the content there.   Can you please clarify how you are trying to access the data and in what way it is not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(var item in dict.Values)
{
      foreach(var tuple in item)
      {
            var someString = tuple.Item1;
            var someInt = tuple.Item2;
      }
}
```

edit: or this

```
   var someList = dict[SOME KEY];

   foreach(var tuple in someList)
      {
            var someString = tuple.Item1;
            var someInt = tuple.Item2;
      }
```

Comment: Iteration of a dictionary is rarely the correct approach.  Either you are using the wrong data structure or you are unaware of key lookups.

Comment: Of course, but if the key is unknown there is really nothing else to do.

Comment: I don't think there is enough context from the OP currently to know whether or not the key IS known.  We still don't know how the OP is actually trying to consume the dictionary.

Comment: and my example is completely wrong.  edit: now its right

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're asking for, but here's some sample code I think might help.

```
string input = "value";

var dict = new Dictionary<string,List<Tuple<string,int>>>(); 

dict.Add(input, new List<Tuple<string, int>>() { new Tuple<string, int> ("this is a string", 20) });

var extractedList = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
dict.TryGetValue(input, out extractedList);

foreach (Tuple<string,int> tuple in extractedList) {
    Console.WriteLine("the string value: " + tuple.Item1 + " and the int: " + tuple.Item2.ToString());
}
```